# Error during execution of Packet Sniffing command

Tags: networking, virtualbox, packet-sniffer, wlan, kali-linux

Step1:
I have shifted my mode to Monitor and also checked by executing the following command in terminal

`iwconfig`

I got the result as

```
lo    no wireless extensions.
ethos no wireless extensions.
wlan0 IEEE 802.11 Mode: Monitor Tx-Power=20 dBm Retry short long  
      limit:2 RTS thr:off Fragment thr:off Power Management: off
```

Then I have executed the following command for packet sniffing

`airodump-ng wlan0`

This is the error I got

```
ioctl(SIOCSIFFLAGS) failed: No such file or directory
Failed initializing wireless card(s): wlan0
```

I am using kali-linux in my virtual box. Having a wireless adapter which has all the compatibility and also supports the monitor mode and even packet injection (le0xsys LEO-HG 150N I think the chip Ralink 802.11n WLAN)

I have no clue why the error is coming. Please help me to fix this issue.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Which version of which Linux distribution are you using? Is this in a virtualbox vm? Which wireless card are you using, and is it on the compatiblity list? https://www.aircrack-ng.org/doku.php?id=compatible_cards

Comment: I am using kali in my virtual box. I am using a wireless  adapter which has all the compatibility list (le0xsys LEO-HG 150N I think with Ralink 802.11n  WLAN)